# cannot response.write on connection node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I wrote this code in node.js :

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('start\n');
    var mysql      = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'hostname',
      user     : 'user',
      password : 'pass',
      database : 'dbname',
    });

    connection.connect();

    connection.query('SELECT code FROM user_type', function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
            //This for is to run on all the results
            for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
            res.write('name:',rows[i].code);
        }
    });

    connection.end();

  res.end('End');
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server running');
```

my questions are:
1. why did the res.write in the for loop print nothing in my html page?
2. what to write instead of 2 in the for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The issue is the timing of execution.

   Since `connection.query()` is asynchronous, it delays the execution of the callback `function` to when the query finishes, but allows the surrounding block of code to continue in the meantime. This results in `res.end('End')` being executed before `res.write('name:',rows[i].code)`.

   To also delay `res.end()`, move it inside the callback:

   ```
   connection.query(..., function(err, rows, fields) {
       if (err) throw err;

       for (...) {
           res.write('name:',rows[i].code);
       }
       res.end('End');
   });
   ```
2. `rows` should be an `Array` when there isn't an `err`, so you can use its [`length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length):

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   ```

   It's also a common practice to store the value of `length` in a local variable:

   ```
   for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
   ```